# How to pass backslash (\) as an argument to system verilog macro

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to write a macro to be used in netlist simulations to concatenate individual bits into a bus:

```
`define BUS(arg) {  ``arg``[3] ,``arg``[2] ,``arg``[1] ,``arg``[0] }
```

and use it like below:

```
assign checker_intf.signal = `BUS(`DUT_INTERNAL_PATH.\signal) ;
```

Notice that the `signal` has a backslash in it. However, compiler is not allowing this and throws `Following verilog source has syntax error` at the line number where macro is called, while expanding the macro during preprocessing.

I can split the argument into 2 and proceed, but would like to know if backslash can be passed as argument.

I tried `\\` and \ between backticks , but both gave same error. I'm using VCS simulator. The error printed only has the above said information and no other specifics

Comment: try with \\\\ where the first two backslash will add a backslash and the last two backslash will by scaped for the first

Comment: @WhiteAB I tried your suggestion, the result was same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simply that you need to end any escaped identifier with whitespace.

```
assign checker_intf.signal = `BUS(`DUT_INTERNAL_PATH.\signal ) ;
```

Note the space before the closing `)`

Also, you don't need any ``` `` ```'s in your macro

```
`define BUS(arg) { arg [3], arg [2] ,arg [1] ,arg [0] }
```

``` `` ``` is just for forming new identifier names from macro arguments, like if you needed to do something like

```
`define BUS(arg) { arg``_3, arg``_2 ,arg``_1 ,arg``_0 }
```

Comment: Giving space helped. I didn't know that the space requirement at the end is needed during preprocessing itself. So I had added this space in the macro definition.  But I worry that the extra space in the argument would make the expansion `\signal [3] ` (extra space between signal and square bracket) instead of `\signal[3] `. I shall wait and see if simulator is okay with that during elaboration. Thanks

Comment: _Any_ use of an escaped identifier requires it be terminated by a whitespace character. Also, whitespace is always optional between any other tokens like select `[]` brackets.

Comment: At elaboration time, I got cross module reference errors. VCS has removed ` \ ` and `  `  from the expansion. From the compile log, expansion looks `{<design_path>.signal[3],<design_path>.signal[2],<design_path>.signal[1],<design_path>.signal[0]}` . Looks like RTL signals now, without space and backslash.

Comment: I was able to get backslashes in the expansion by passing 2 backslashes `\`BUS(\`DUT_INTERNAL_PATH.\\signal )` but any amount of spaces I added during macro call or inside definition gets removed by compiler resulting in elab error.